# Regex with cumulative effect

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a regex that replaces numbers and whitespace with a hyphen.

```
/[^\s\d-]/
```

This works well, but there is a chance here of having multiple hyphens next to each other, which I don't want.

If the following string was passed: `I  am a bad str1 ng`

I would want `I-am-a-bad-str-ng` i.e. with only single hyphens. Is it possible to change the regex to do this?

Comment: Did you mean you currently get `str--ng`?

Comment: Are you trying to create a slug?

Comment: Yes, well it is a limited form of a filename

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small modification:

```
/[^\s\d-]+/
         ^
```

The `+` greedy quantifier means "one or more iterations, as many as possible". Therefore this Regex will match one more iterations, as many as possible, of your character class in a row.